# How to center a datepicker placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, format

I have

```
<input required type="text" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" id="fecha_form" name="fecha_form">
```

And it seems like:

[image: Datepicker input]

### how do I to center the placeholder to the center of the input?

Comment: use `style="text-align: center;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do this by these lines of css

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* For Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* For Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

place this tag inside head tag it will fix your issue across most popular browsers

```
<style type="text/css">

    #fecha_form::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       text-align: center;
    }

    #fecha_form:-moz-placeholder { 
       text-align: center;  
    }

    #fecha_form::-moz-placeholder { 
       text-align: center;  
    }

    #fecha_form:-ms-input-placeholder {  
       text-align: center; 
    }
    
</style>
```